# Blink or flash text on update of data from websocket

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using vuejs with single file components and vuex.  Data is streaming in over a websocket connection, and I'm using Vuex to manage state and bind the data to display in various components.  That all works great.

I just use mapState in the component file, and then display that value in the html.

For some of the data, I'd like to apply some transition whenever a value changes.  i.e. 
- flash/blink the value
- flash/blink the background color

I'm displaying numerical values, and thought might look nice to briefly flash green when the number changes up and red when the number changes down.  Still debating if I want to flash the actual text, or the div containing the text.  Also debating if I want to revert color back to black after the brief color flash.

Is there a way to easily to do this in vuejs?  I understand how to use computed values, but how can I fire some color change animation when the value updates from vuex.

Comment: Set some color properties that will change when value is updated and use them as inline css.

Comment: I thought that would work for setting the static color of an object ( I use this method in other places.)  How can I "BLINK" or animate the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options, depending on what you eventually decide the effect to be.

Here is the simplest solution. Use a `watch`er on the `computed` getter and a conditional class to style your values.

```
data: {
  myValue: {
    prev: 150,
    latest: 100
  }
},
computed: {
  valueInStore() {
    return this.$store.getters.value
  }
},
watch: {
  valueInStore(newValue, oldValue) {
    this.myValue.prev = oldValue
    this.myValue.latest = newValue
  }
}
```

To display the correct css class you then

```
<div :class="getColorClass(myValye)">{{ myValue.latest }}</div>

...

methods: {
  // method instead of computed since you were talking about multiple values
  getColorClass(foo) {
    return this.myValue.prev < this.myValue.latest ? 'green' : 'red'
  },
}
```

Depending on your needs you might need do adjust for the `prev == latest` case.

Now you can use any css styles or animations you want in the `.green` and `.red` classes.